# invalid literal for float(): 01/06/2017 22:00

Tags: python, csv, date, pandas

The data is from csv file and I read it with pandas.I used pyplot to plot, it should be just like: x as the time, y as the wind speed. I think the problem is caused by selection or indexing. I only want the data from row 22-25 and then plot it. Here are the data and codes:

```
      time              Unnamed: 2
22    01/06/2017 13:00  23 
23    01/06/2017 16:00  22
24    01/06/2017 19:00  15
25    01/06/2017 22:00  10


import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = pd.read_csv('J:/internship/forecast/6.1/forecast_report_Bahrain.csv')
m10wind = a['Unnamed: 2'][22:26]
time= a['time'][22:26]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig,ax.set_xlabel("Time(+3UTC)")
fig,ax.set_ylabel("10m wind speed (knots)")
ax.plot(time, m10wind, 'r', label='GFS Forecast')
leg = ax.legend(loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0))
plt.savefig('1st June wind of Bahrain.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

full error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-9ab81b2b3775>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/xiaoshen.sun/.spyder/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/xiaoshen.sun/.spyder')

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/xiaoshen.sun/.spyder/temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    ax.plot(time, m10wind, 'r', label='GFS Forecast')

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1891, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1407, in plot
    self.add_line(line)

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1787, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1809, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 989, in get_path
    self.recache()

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 676, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)

  File "C:\tools\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 01/06/2017 22:00
```

Comment: could you please give us the exact error?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]. For example just create a small custom `a` DataFrame that can be used to reconstruct the error.

Comment: Lots of chained indexing... yikes! I would read up on this for indexing best practices- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue (likely) relates to the `datetime` column not being formatted as such. I was able to convert the column using `pd.to_datetime()` and plot this data without any issues. Your plotting is also incorrect and will probably throw an error- `fig, ax` is meant to unpack a tuple. `ax` contains the `plot` method (see below).

```
df
                  time  Unnamed: 2
22 2017-01-06 13:00:00          23
23 2017-01-06 16:00:00          22
24 2017-01-06 19:00:00          15
25 2017-01-06 22:00:00          10
```

Convert:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
```

Plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.time, df['Unnamed: 2'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! I use subplot because there will be 2 different series of data. Thanks again.